# Can I make a type "sealed except for internal types"

Tags: c#, internal, sealed

I want to make a type that can be inherited from by types in the same assembly, but cannot be inherited from outside of the assembly. I do want the type to be visible outside of the assembly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can make the constructor internal:

```
public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass() { }
}
```

Every class that derives from a base class must call a constructor of the base class in its constructor. Since it can't call the constructor if the base class is in a different assembly, the derived class doesn't compile.

Comment: and how do you create an instance outside your assembly?

Comment: @tanascius: add a factory method, for example?

Comment: yes that's possible, although it is unclear if the OP needs to create instances at all (he talks about *visible*, only) ... +1

Comment: `public class EvilInternalClass : MyClass { public EvilInternalClass() { } }`

Comment: Note that any `static` variables/`static` methods/`const` values should be marked as `internal` or `private` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question could still benefit from a semantically correct answer... which is "no". You can't declare a type as "sealed to external assemblies only".

Don't get me wrong: dtb's answer is a good one. An internal constructor is the closest you can get from the desired result.

However, I think that anyone reading this should be aware that in this example, `MyClass` wouldn't be described as being sealed at runtime. It is unlikely that this will ever be a problem, but if may cause logic based on reflection (from your code or a 3rd party library) to act differently on this particular type. It's something to keep in mind.

And now, to further expand on dtb's sample code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass() { }

    // This factory method will be accessible from external assemblies, making your class instantiable yet still "sealed"
    public static MyClass Create()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

This way you can still create instances of `MyClass` from outside the owning assembly, while still keeping control over inheritance.