# Prevent inheritance of base class

Tags: c#

If I have 3 classes as follows:

```
abstract class A {}

public class B : A {}

public class C: A {}
```

I want to force other code to use B or C directly, or inherit from either `B` or `C`. I don't want other code to inherit directly from `A`.

Is this even possible?

`A` cannot be private since `B` and `C` must be public, making A private would cause "Inconsistent accessibility". `A` can't be `internal` for the same reason.

Why do I want this?

I have designed an API, the response of which must include either property x, or both properties y & z, but not all 3. It also includes a bunch of other properties that are common to both possibilities. i.e. -

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "w": { ... }
      }
    }, 
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "x": { ... }
          }
        }, 
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "y": { ... },
            "z": { ... }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: While writing out the question, I've actually realised that I don't need this after all, since it would actually be useful to still have property x (but auto-generated) on the y+z output, thus I can simplify the class structure. Keeping the question active though since it could be useful to others.

Comment: Make the constructor(s) of `A` `internal`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make a type "sealed except for internal types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072119/can-i-make-a-type-sealed-except-for-internal-types)

Comment: Kind of, except `internal` won't really work for me since the "other" code I mentioned is actually in the same library. It might work if this wasn't the case though. If it helps, A, B + C are all in the same file. (B + C are stubs)

Comment: how about using interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make `B` and `C` part of `A` you can mark the constructor of `A` `private` so no other classes can inherit directly from `A`:

```
public class A
{
    private A()
    {

    }

    public class B: A
    {
        public B()
        {

        }
    }

    public class C: A
    {
        public C()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The downside however is that you now have to refer to `B` as `A.B` (see edit, this is not needed), but functionality wise the rest of the application is able to instantiate and use classes of type `A.B` and `A.C` and inherit from them while prohibiting the ability to instantiate or use `A` directly (even in the same file/assembly).

So this is invalid anywhere outside of `A`:

```
public class D: A
{

}
```

But this you can use anywhere:

```
public class E : A.B
{

}
```

Edit: As noted by Jonathan Barclay you prevent having to use `A.B` by the following using directive, which will allow you to inherit as normal:

```
using static MyNamespace.A;

public class D : B
{

}
```

Comment: Now that I've seen this, its pretty obvious!
I guess also there is nothing to stop from doing this outside of A, but still in the same file:
`public class B : A.B { }`

Comment: "_The downside however is that you now have to refer to `B` as `A.B`_" Not necessarily; you can add `using static YourNamespace.A;`.